# Recaptcha is always giving error "Answer to recaptcha is wrong"

Tags: php, drupal-7, recaptcha, drupal-modules

I am using reCAPTCHA on my drupal7 login form, the version of captcha and reCAPTCHA are latest, CAPTCHA 7.x-1.5
 and reCAPTCHA 7.x-2.3. After filling the captcha and hitting submit button I am getting the error "The answer you entered for the CAPTCHA was not correct".I have done many R & D on this but no success.
 Can you please help me to solve this issue ?. I am also attaching the screenshot

Comment: Please reply as soon as possible, thanks!!

Comment: where is screenshot.